# Running a shell script to a remote linux server from the local window?

Tags: unix, ssh, putty, plink

I am trying to run a shell script to execute a binary on a remote linux box. Both the binary and the shell script are on my local window machine. Is there any way through which i can run the binary to the remote machine directly from windows through command line tools like *PLINK*?

I don't want to put the binary and the script to all the remote linux boxes which 
i want them to run on,Instead I want to run the shell script which will intern invoke the binary and do the desirable functions directly through my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the shell script remotely, just by piping it through ssh:

```
cat my_script.sh | ssh -T my_server
```

(Or whatever the windows/plink equivalent is.)

However, you can't run the binary remotely through a pipe, the file will have to exist on the remote server. You can do this by pushing the file from your windows machine to a known location on the remote server, and then editing your script to expect the file to exist in that location:

```
scp my_binary my_server:/tmp
cat my_script.sh | ssh -T my_server
```

And then just have your script run that binary:

```
/tmp/my_binary
```

Or you can write the script so that it pulls the binary file from a central location where you're hosting it:

```
wget -O /tmp/my_binary http://my_fileserver/my_binary
/tmp/my_binary
```

Note, if the shell script doesn't do anything else besides invoke the binary, then you don't need it. You can just fire the commands directly through ssh:

```
ssh -T my_server "cd /tmp && wget http://my_fileserver/my_binary && ./my_binary"
```

Comment: What about the login credentials it will ask every time my script runs ?

Comment: If you don't want it to prompt every time, you can use an SSH key that has no passphrase.

Comment: Ok yeah makes sense..Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy the binary to the remote Linux box before it can be executed. However, you could have a script on the windows machine that uses sftp to transfer the binary program to a temporary directory under `/tmp` before running it, so there is no manual setup required.